# Div "eating" in to an image above - What's the terminology?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

From what I can see the div below sort of eats into the image above as you scroll down creating what I think is a nice visual.

My only problem is I don't know what the terminology is to search for a tutorial on the process itself.

Does anybody know what search term I would use to find a good tutorial? I have literally tried everything I thought it might be called.

Example on a site where it is used: http://www.anakin.co/en

Comment: [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com) would probably be a better place to ask questions like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term is called *parallax scrolling*.

The following link is a good tutorial, and explains how to achieve this in just CSS.
http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/.

Regarding the cutout effect I believe that is called clip masking.

Answer (score 0):

The main content is on an overlay. If you look at the code though, in the css you'll see the "clip" property. It's since been deprecated, but it's been replaced by "clip-path". Showing parts of an image is called clipping/Masking and I believe you can find what you're looking for here:

https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

EDIT: The background image is using parallax, which gives the background image "motion" when you scroll. But the actual effect of having that background show through is the clipping/masking in the article.

Answer (score 0):

It's called `Parallax scrolling` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling